# Display vulkan rendering in Swing

Tags: java, jogl, vulkan

I'm currently working on finding a way to display Vulkan rendering inside a Swing context

I've noticed that the GLJPanel from JOGL allowed me to get the underlying native surface which is what is needed in order to give a surface to Vulkan to render to, I thought that I could then make Vulkan display in it yet I get an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION in the vulkan-1.dll at the moment when I call vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormat

Obviously I did not think that it would be that simple, but still it surprises me that this problem happens while I'm manipulating a native surface that otherwise works great when generated by glfw for example

Is there something I missed ?

Comment: Is there any OpenGL context already created by JOGL? If there is it may be a problem because spec doesn't allow other APIs to use the same surface/window. But I'm not sure how hardware vendors treat this and if this can cause such problems. But it is something we should keep in mind.

Comment: JOGL doesn't support Vulkan yet but feel free to contribute :)

Answer (score 1):

> JOGL allowed me to get the underlying native surface which is what is needed in order to give a surface to Vulkan to render to

...

> `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormat`

Are you suggesting that you're taking this surface you get from JOGL and passing it directly to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormat`?  That won't work.  You need to use one of the surface creation functions listed [here](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.0.33.0/linux/vkspec.chunked/ch29s02.html) and you need to make sure that when creating the instance you requested the appropriate extensions, i.e. `VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME` and whatever platform specific extension you need like `VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME` or `VK_KHR_ANDROID_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME`, etc.

Without including the code you're using the create the surface and pass it to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormat`, there's no more diagnosis that can be done.

Comment: Yes it's what I was trying and I wasn't expecting it to work well, but I thought it was worth the try :)